# How to express REGEX OR in in digits?

Tags: python, regex

```
\d{1,2}｜\d{5,}
(\d{1,2})｜(\d{5,})
```

I want to match 1-2 digits or more than 5 digits. Why both patterns above not working? I suppose this should match the second half:

```
s = 12345
```

S is a digit, not str. But it doesn't match at all.

Comment: You need to anchor it. Otherwise 1-2 digits will match the first 2 digits of a 4 digit number

Comment: @Barmar How to anchor it?

Comment: `^` at beginning, `$` at end

Comment: If I test, '12345', it doesn't match at all.

Comment: You have to convert the number to a string before matching with regexp

Comment: Your example seems off. There are 5 digits present with logic requesting a match of 1-2 or more than 5 digits. Under these conditions, there would be no match, right?

Comment: I think you are using a different char for the pipe `|` See https://regex101.com/r/44whfU/1 The alternation will first match 2 digits, then again 2 digits and the last single digit due to the `\d{1,2}`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing word bounds. \b around the things you want to catch.

Something like this should do the trick.

```
\b\d{1,2}\b|\b\d{5,}\b
```

Here's a handy cheat sheet I like to use. [Link](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Comment: @Barmar OP mentioned only digits.

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear if they mean a word consisting only of digits, or find digits anywhere in the input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the spaces around the pipe.
2. Put the largest regex in the first part of alternation: `\d{5,}|\d{1,2}`
3. Anchor your regex: `^(?:\d{5,}|\d{1,2})$`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/6U2skG/1)